# Trigger Button click event every 5 seconds in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a button with the following click event:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serverName server = new serverName("localhost");
            int entryNum = System.Convert.ToInt32(txtEntry.Text);
            Entry entry;
            Entry.Load(out entry, entryNum, server);
            if(entry != null)
            {
                lblName.Text = entry.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                lblName.Text = "Error: no entry found!";
            }
            if (entry.Status != string.Empty)
            {
                lblSeverity.Text = entry.Severity.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Basically every time the button is clicked we run a query to our server and return the results of my entry to labels on my aspx page.

I want this event to fire every 5 seconds automatically without the user having to click the button every time.  How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by JavaScript and JQuery

```
setInterval(function(){ $('#YOUR_BUTTON_CLIENT_ID').click() }, 5000);
```